# What happens if Cosmo and Wanda are revealed by Timmy or Chloe?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-fairly-oddparents

In *The Fairly Oddparents*, Season 10, Timmy and Chloe must share Cosmo and Wanda.

What happens if one of them reveals the fairies' existence? Are both of them screwed?